# PyMC3 regression with change point

Tags: python, regression, pymc, pymc3

I saw the examples of how to do change point analysis with pymc3, but it seems that I'm missing something because the results I get are far from true values. Here's a toy example.

Data:

[image: toy data]

Script:

```
from pymc3 import *
from numpy.random import uniform, normal

bp_u = 30 #switch point
c_u = [1, -1] #intercepts before and after switch point
beta_u = [0, -0.02]  #slopes before & after switch point

x = uniform(0,90, 200)

y = (x < bp_u)*(c_u[0]+beta_u[0]*x) + (x >= bp_u)*(c_u[1]+beta_u[1]*x) + normal(0,0.1,200)

with Model() as sw_model:

    sigma = HalfCauchy('sigma', beta=10, testval=1.)

    switchpoint = Uniform('switchpoint', lower=x.min(), upper=x.max(), testval=45)

    # Priors for pre- and post-switch intercepts and slopes
    intercept_u1 = Uniform('Intercept_u1', lower=-10, upper=10)
    intercept_u2 = Uniform('Intercept_u2', lower=-10, upper=10)
    x_coeff_u1 = Normal('x_u1', 0, sd=20)
    x_coeff_u2 = Normal('x_u2', 0, sd=20)

    intercept = switch(switchpoint < x, intercept_u1, intercept_u2)
    x_coeff = switch(switchpoint < x, x_coeff_u1, x_coeff_u2)

    likelihood = Normal('y', mu=intercept + x_coeff * x, sd=sigma, observed=y)

    start = find_MAP() 

with sw_model:
    step1 = NUTS([intercept_u1, intercept_u2, x_coeff_u1, x_coeff_u2])
    step2 = NUTS([switchpoint])

    trace = sample(2000, step=[step1, step2], start=start, progressbar=True)
```

And here are the results:

[image: segmented regression results]

As you can see, they are quite different from the initial values. What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you set sigma to a small, fixed number (e.g., 0.01), you'll get results that are reasonable. I don't actually understand _why_ the code isn't able to determine this on its own.

Comment: This is what I get with setting sigma=0.01. http://imgur.com/2Q6TsNJ

Comment: Thanks! That helps. But in the end I switched to discrete breaking point with Metropolis sampling, that also greatly increases the speed and accuracy.

Comment: If you are open to an R solution, this can be modeled in the `mcp` package using `fit = mcp(list(y ~ 1, ~ 1 + x), data)`. Plot the posteriors and traces with `plot_pars(fit)`.

Comment: @JonasLindeløv, thanks, I don't really need it anymore but it's good to know about the R solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end it seems that switching to discrete breaking point with Metropolis sampling resolves the issue. Here's the final model:

```
with Model() as sw_model:

    sigma = HalfCauchy('sigma', beta=10, testval=1.)

    switchpoint = DiscreteUniform('switchpoint', lower=0, upper=90, testval=45)

    # Priors for pre- and post-switch intercepts and slopes
    intercept_u1 = Uniform('Intercept_u1', lower=-10, upper=10, testval = 0)
    intercept_u2 = Uniform('Intercept_u2', lower=-10, upper=10, testval = 0)
    x_coeff_u1 = Normal('x_u1', 0, sd=20)
    x_coeff_u2 = Normal('x_u2', 0, sd=20)

    intercept = switch(switchpoint < x, intercept_u1, intercept_u2)
    x_coeff = switch(switchpoint < x, x_coeff_u1, x_coeff_u2)

    likelihood = Normal('y', mu=intercept + x_coeff * x, sd=sigma, observed=y)

    start = find_MAP() 

    step1 = NUTS([intercept_u1, intercept_u2, x_coeff_u1, x_coeff_u2])
    step2 = Metropolis([switchpoint])

    trace = sample(20000, step=[step1, step2], start=start, njobs=4,progressbar=True)
```

[image: the traceplot]

Comment: From memory, NUTS assumes continuity (and differentiability?) of likelihood function: a breakpoint introduces a discontinuity and hence Metropolis works but NUTS does not.

Comment: Thanks for posting and following-up on this. I am wondering if you can update this to see how you can post the results with the latest build of pymc3 and `az.plot_trace` and `return_inferencedata=True`